# How to smoothly change text in UILabel

Tags: swift, animation, uilabel

I have some UILabels next to each other containing text.
It could be:
2x-5 = 3

I can drag "-5" to the other side.
2x = 3-5

It then moves in to place next to "3" and then I change the sign from - to +, within a UIView.animate() function.
Because "+" is a little bit wider than "-" the text goes past the limits of the UILabel, which cuts of the text in one side.

So I resize the labels width, but it is visible when using the application.

I have tried changing the size of the label before I change the sign, just adding a lot of space.
But it still cuts some of the text off.

Here is the code:

```
let v = UILabel()
v.text = "+5"
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
     v.frame.size.width = v.intrinsicContentSize.width + 20
     v.text = "-5"
     v.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 45)
     v.textAlignment = .center
     v.frame.size.width = v.intrinsicContentSize.width
     v.frame.size.height = v.intrinsicContentSize.height
}
```

Optimally I want the label not to cut off any of the text when the width of the text is changed.

(Edit: removed other question unrelated to main question)

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: To be honest, you are asking more than one question, which is frowned on here. So let's just concentrate on you main (IMHO) question, a UILabel and it's size and intrinsic size for the text it contains. (And ignoring the question about smoothly adding the "+" sign.) You really have a single choice - assign the UILabel a *constant* horizontal size. Period. I considered computing the intrinsic size and adjusting the font size based on that, but it doesn't sound like it fits your needs after seeing you understand the intrinsic size....

Comment: You have three options. (1) Change the intrinsic size by altering the font size. Won't work for you. (2) Rethink your layout of using a single UILabel. Doesn't sound that works for you either. So you are left with the final option (3) Clearly declare the size of the UILabel. You didn't post any code that addresses if you are using IB, using auto layout, or how. But *both* in code *and* in a storyboard, you *can set up constraints that dictate the horizontal size of a UILabel. That seems like your only option. Just be sure it's long enough!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not using any auto layout, since it has caused me some problems with automatically resizing text, I need the text in wvery label to always be the same. And I don't use any IB. 
In the 3. option you mention, what do you mean by clearly declare the size of the UILabel?